# iPad App became crashed when use CFURLDestroyResource

Tags: iphone, ftp

I use this code to delete file by FTP Connection

```
url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"ftp://sikmac3:remuza@localhost/Test.php"];
CFURLRef urlRef;
urlRef = (CFURLRef) url;
Boolean test = CFURLDestroyResource(urlRef, status);
if(test){
    NSLog(@"deletion success");
}else{
    NSLog(@"deletion failed");
}

CFRelease(urlRef);
[url release];
```

the file was deleted. but application became crashed/ terminated immediately.

Any one know about this case. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
SInt32 status = 0;
Boolean test = CFURLDestroyResource(urlRef, &status);
```

You must pass a pointer to a valid SInt32 where the function can return the result.

Comment: @reni: How are you doing it..  ?Its not working for me, does not delete the file.

Comment: CFURLDestroyResource is now deprecated in IOS7 but I have had no luck at all sorting out what to use instead.